# React-three-fiber orthographic camera zoom

Tags: reactjs, 3d, three.js, webgl, render

Я использую в своем React приложении библиотеку [react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber). У меня есть `canvas` в котором отрисовывается меш(3d-объект), я использую **orthographic** камеру и мне нужно по событию `onClick` увеличивать параметр камеры **zoom**. Я создал useState `zoomSize` по клику увеличиваю значение через `setZoomSize()` и оно меняется, но камера не реагирует и не приближается. Почему изменения не влияют на сцену? Это связанно с рендерингом? И как тогда мне по клику увеличить свой меш?

```
...imports


export default function Viewer() {

const tomograms = useSelector((state) => state.tomograms);
const [zoomSize, setZoomSize] = useState(1.7);


const changeZoom = (e) => {
  setZoomSize(zoomSize + 0.1);
};

return (
    <div onClick={(e) => changeZoom(e)}>
      <Canvas
        orthographic
        camera={{zoom: zoomSize}}
      >
            <primitive
              position={[-127, -145, -105]}
              object={
                new THREE.Mesh(
                  tomograms.r2.stackHelper._slice._geometry,
                  tomograms.r2.stackHelper._slice._material
                )
              }
            />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я смог решить эту проблему используя хук [useThree](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/hooks#use-three) и достав из него `camera`, я напрямую меняю ей параметр `zoom`.

```
export default function Viewer() {

const tomograms = useSelector((state) => state.tomograms);
const [zoomSize, setZoomSize] = useState(1.7);


const changeZoom = (e) => {
 setZoomSize(zoomSize + 0.1);
};

const Tomogram = (r) => {
const { camera } = useThree();

camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

camera.zoom = r.zoom;

return (
  <mesh
    position={r.position}
    geometry={r.rN.stackHelper._slice._geometry}
    material={r.rN.stackHelper._slice._material}
  />
);
};

return (
<div onClick={(e) => changeZoom(e)}>
  <Canvas
    orthographic
    camera={{zoom: zoomSize}}
  >
          <Tomogram
            rN={tomograms.r2}
            position={new THREE.Vector3(-127, -145, -105)}
            zoom={zoomSizeR2}
          />
  </Canvas>
</div>
);
}
```